# sublime text 3 keybinding save with encode + utf8

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

As the title says.
I want to make keyboard shortcut for save with encoding + UTF-8 . Anyone has idea how to do that in key bindings file of Submlime text 3?

Answer (score 2):

Open *`Preferences`* -> *`Key Bindings`* and enter the following into your `sublime-keymap - User` file:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+e"], "command": "save", "args": {"encoding": "utf-8"} },
```

(changing the key combination if you wish) and save. Remove trailing comma if above is the only custom key binding.

**Result** exhibits immediately:

[image: Ctrl E]

Comment: Worked on sublime 2